# How to display category name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

i want to display the search item name in search page as heading.
(here it is displaying value instead of name)

I am searching through ransack.

My search view

```
<%= form_tag location_path, :method=>'get' do %> 
<%= select_tag :q, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, params[:q]), :class=>"btn1 btn-default1 dropdown-button1 dropdown-toggle"%>
 <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn1 home-search-button" >
<%end %>
```

my search controller

```
def location
    q = params[:q]
    @key = q
    @property = Property.ransack(location_or_category_name_cont: q).result(distinct: true)
  end
```

MY location.html.erb

HERE IS WHERE I WANT DISPLAY THE PROPERTY NAME as

```
 <h1>Properties in <%=@key%></h1>
```

i am getting output like this.

[image]

BUT, instead of `2`, I want to get output like this `Properties in Residential`.
I have a category table with 3 category with fields id(1 ,2,3) and category_names (residential commericial and Finance.

Any help is appreciatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming category_name is the column of your categories table:

`@key = Category.find(q).category_name`

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
@key = Category.find_by(:id=>q)
```

In view:

```
<h1>Properties in <%= @key.category_name if @key.present?%></h1>
```